# git svn clone an entire svn repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

When I clone our svn repo using `git svn` i pass it arguments to tell it where the head, branches, tags... etc are and it pulls the main code base properly. in addition to trunk and branches we also have directories for:

- the website,
- and one for 3rd-party apps
- the build system
- a bunch of others.

How do I get git-svn to pull these also?

can I run something like

```
 git svn clone -T Dev -T website -T build -T other -b Branches -t Tags
```

and have the end result end up like:

```
/git-repo/Dev/
             /productA/
             /projectX/
         /website/
             /http-root/
             /.../
         /build
         /other/ 
             /3rdParty/
```

could I do this by creating one new repo and creating sub-projects?
how about making separate repos and then merging them somehow? If I do this what would I put for the branches and tags directory for the ones that are not Dev (Dev is Trunk)?

Comment: Better to describe why you want to pull those 3rd-party apps as well, normally they should not be part of version control system. And this is a good chance when you switch to git You can store those into well defined directories, like /opt/<3pp vendor>/<package name>/<version>/<files>

Comment: They are source code to apps and packages we had to fork.

Comment: It depends on how you use the 3pp, and I give two suggestion.

Firstly put 3pp codes into another git repo

- 3pp codes are shared with lib or other packages (if java, then maven artifact) with your own codes  
- Work towards multi git repository, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862/how-do-you-organise-multiple-git-repositories

Hope it is useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Comment: This question is asking how to specify the structure of the SVN repo to be cloned for cases where it is structured as distinct projects within the same repo. an answer explaining how to clone SVN to git does not address this question. (and both of these questions are over five years old now)